# Nested comments in a post

Tags: ember.js

I am working on a ember app and I would like to allow nested comments in a post.

For this, I created a `Component` to display each comment in a post. And inside this component I do a recursive call to display the "nested comments"

```
<article class="post-comment">

  <p> {{comment.text}}  commented by {{comment.user.name}} {{moment-from-now comment.date }} </p>

  {{input id=comment.id  class="form-control" placeholder=(t "enter.title") value=commentCommentText}}

  <button class="btn " {{action "doComment" comment commentCommentText}}>comment</button>
  {{#if (can "delete comment")}}
    <button class="btn btn-danger " {{action "deleteComment" comment }}>delete</button>
  {{/if}}

  {{#if comment.comments.length}}
   {{#each comment.comments as |nestedComment| }}
    <p>{{nestedComment.text}}</p>
      {{#post-comment comment=nestedComment action="commentComment" cancel="deleteComment"}} {{/post-comment}}
   {{/each}}
  {{/if}}

</article>
```

And it is called from the template like this:

```
{{#each post.comments as |postComment| }}

   <li class="media list-group-item p-a">
     {{#post-comment comment=postComment submit="commentComment" cancel="deleteComment"}} 
     {{/post-comment}}

   </li>
{{/each}}
```

But it gives me an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Honestly I don't know if this recursive call is the best way to do this. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the error? {{#post-comment}} Why are u using it as a block "#" ? Otherwise your code seems fine

Comment: `{{#if comment.comments.length}}` seems unnecessary. But it should work. Can you provide a crashing ember-twiddle?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i updated the question with more data.